# Preventing a type from being put into a Vec

Tags: rust, types, move

Imagine that you create a type, and for some reason, you don't want its user to be able to put it into a `Vec`, `Rc`, etc.

```rust
struct ImmovableObject<T>(T);

fn main() {
    // Should cause an error, ImmovableObject can't be put in / owned by a Vec.
    let mut x = vec![ImmovableObject(42)];
}
```

I looked into the various methods of pinning it, but they all require some form of reference.  Is there a way to do this without any indirection?

Comment: Can you provide an example of when you would not want it to be put inside a `Vec`, `Rc`, etc.?

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: `Vec` dosent have any constraints for the data that can be stored in it so I wouldn't think this is possible. Whats the motivation for it? There may be an easier solution.

Comment: There's nothing special about `Vec`, it has properties like any other structure, so to prevent that, you have to prevent creating it in the first place. Note it isn't being moved per-se into the vector, it's likely being built where it needs to go. Remember you can prevent something from being copied, and you can [`pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/) it as well.

Comment: that don't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of a runtime check, but it's ugly to use (basically need to check it everytime something is created). It would also have to be implemented for each type that should be banned from containing `ImmovableObject`, and it won't work if the `ImmovableObject` is contained in another object

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait MaybePanic { 
    fn maybe_panic(&self);
}

struct ImmovableObject<T>(T);
impl<T> MaybePanic for T {
    default fn maybe_panic(&self) { }
}

impl<T> MaybePanic for Vec<ImmovableObject<T>> {
    fn maybe_panic(&self) { panic!("Mustn't store an ImmovableObject in a Vector"); }
}

fn main() {
    let obj = ImmovableObject(42_usize);
    obj.maybe_panic(); // ok
    let tuple = (ImmovableObject(42_usize), );
    let v = vec![tuple];
    v.maybe_panic(); // ok
    let v = vec![obj];
    v.maybe_panic(); // runtime error
}
```